# How to force CSGO server to change teams at mid rounds?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, hosting

I have `mp_maxrounds "30"` but they are all played on one side, what I want is to have 15 rounds per side.

Comment: gamedev.stackexchange.com is a better place for this. It is offtopic here I am afraid.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness gamedev is for **professional and amateur video/computer game developers**. The question fits here better... He is not developing a video game he is trying to switch the sides with a console command of cs go

Comment: why do you even change the preset values  ? The Server should have by default 15 rounds on each side.

Comment: @Gerret Nope. http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/562/do-mod-development-questions-belong-here And making a mod is essentially developing a game.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness He is developing a mod? Where is a indication that he is developing a mod? I only read here a question for a solution how he is able to force to swap the teams after 15 rounds. I do not think that that is called development... This could be solved with the build in commands!

Comment: i'm just playing with bots, and just use cvars on config file, i'm not developing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "mp_halftime 1" to make the server switch the teams when 1/2 of "mp_maxrounds" has been played.